# Merge data.frames between two lists by one single column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge, col

Here an example of my two lists and data.frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
df2 = data.frame(a = c(111,112,113,114))

lst1 = list(df1, df2)

df3 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), b = c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19))
df4 = data.frame(a = c(111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119), b = c(22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30))

lst2 = list(df3, df4)
```

I need to merge `lst1` with `lst2` by column `a` in order to have `df1` merged with `df3` and `df2` with `df4`.

Here my desired output:

```
> output_lst
[[1]]
   a  b
   1 10
   2 11
   3 12
   4 13
   5 14
   6 15
   7 16

[[2]]
    a  b
1 111 22
2 112 23
3 113 24
4 114 25
```

I tried a lot with both `lapply` and `Map` but without results.
Thanks

Comment: thank you guys...your answers work both with the example but not with my real lists

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I can only think that your real lists are somehow different in structure if a simple merge fails.

Comment: yes, data.frames within lst1 have different number of cols compared to data.frame within lst2...but I don't think this would be a problem

Comment: basically @989 suggestion actually merge the two list but I got NAs within the new columns added. by using Map I get empty data.frames.

Comment: `Map(merge, lst1, lst2, by="a", all.x=TRUE)` I think solves the first issue. You would expect `NA` values if you have the `by=` column value not found in `lst2`. If you are getting empty data.frames it's probably because there are no matches between `lst1` and `lst2` on your `by=` variable - `merge(data.frame(a=1,b=2), data.frame(a=2,c=3), by="a")` for example.

Comment: @thelatemail thank you mate. I spotted the error in one list, i.e. column 'a' as factor! thanks again :-) now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just:

```
Map(merge, lst1, lst2)
#or more explicitly
Map(merge, lst1, lst2, by="a")
```

`Map` is basically a glorified loop doing:

```
merge(lst1[[1]], lst2[[1]], by="a")
#and
merge(lst1[[2]], lst2[[2]], by="a")
```

Comment: tidyversalized: `map2(lst1, lst2, inner_join)` Not really better till you want to combine them into a single data.frame, which is just `map2_df(lst1, lst2, inner_join)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sapply(seq_len(length(lst1)), 
       function(i) list(merge(lst1[[i]], lst2[[i]], by = "a", all.x=TRUE)))

# [[1]]
  # a  b
# 1 1 10
# 2 2 11
# 3 3 12
# 4 4 13
# 5 5 14
# 6 6 15
# 7 7 16

# [[2]]
    # a  b
# 1 111 22
# 2 112 23
# 3 113 24
# 4 114 25
```